# Arithmetic operation resulted in overflow

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and WAMP server for my database

I'm creating a registration page and I encountered this error

> Arithmetic operation resulted in overflow

It is pointing at this part of my code

> ```
> cmd = New MySqlCommand("START TRANSACTION;INSERT INTO person(firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, address, mobile, telephone, email) VALUES ( '" & fn & "', '" & ln & "', '" & gn & "', concat('" + mm + "'," / ",'" + dd + "'," / ",'" + yy + "'), '" & ad & "', '" & mo & "', '" & tl & "', '" & em & "');INSERT account(username, password, access) VALUES( '" & un & "', '" & pw & "', 'user'); COMMIT;")
> ```

Here is my class file

```
 Public Function registerDB(ByVal fn As String, ByVal ln As String, ByVal un As String, ByVal pw As String, ByVal mm As Integer, ByVal dd As Integer, ByVal yy As Integer, ByVal gn As String, ByVal ad As String, ByVal mo As Integer, ByVal tl As Integer, ByVal em As String)
    Dim res As String
    'Try
    cmd = New MySqlCommand("START TRANSACTION;INSERT INTO person(firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, address, mobile, telephone, email) VALUES ( '" & fn & "', '" & ln & "', '" & gn & "', concat('" + mm + "'," / ",'" + dd + "'," / ",'" + yy + "'), '" & ad & "', '" & mo & "', '" & tl & "', '" & em & "');INSERT account(username, password, access) VALUES( '" & un & "', '" & pw & "', 'user'); COMMIT;")
```

And this is my code in the web form

```
    Protected Sub btnRRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRRegister.Click
    Dim rgC As registerClass = New registerClass
    Dim ret As String
    rgC.connectDB()
    ret = rgC.registerDB(tbxFirstname.Text.ToString, tbxLastname.Text.ToString, tbxRUsername.Text.ToString, tbxRPassword.Text.ToString, tbxRMonth.Text.ToString, tbxRDay.Text.ToString, tbxRYear.Text.ToString, rbtRGender.Text.ToString, tbxRAddress.Text.ToString, tbxRMobile.Text.ToString, tbxRTelephone.Text.ToString, tbxREmail.Text.ToString)
```

I'm kind of stuck here, any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you quoting your month-day-year values separatly? And what values are you passing to your SQL-Statement?

Comment: I *think* it may be complaining about dividing by `"',"`. I recommend that you do yourself a favour and (a) use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and (b) use SQL parameters to pass the values to your query.

Comment: The textbox of month-day-year are seperate (They look like this [MM] [DD] [YYYY]). In my SQL statement I try to concatenate them so they would appear as one value in database MM/DD/YYYY. I'm trying to input values from textbox.

Comment: I did encounter an error about String "'," to type Double is not valid.

Comment: Finally worked, used SQL parameters instead. Thanks Andrew!